# how to grep and replace it multiple files and multiples elements on OS X

Tags: sed, grep

I use this `grep` command line on OS X.

`grep -E 'Title|Amount|AwardID|FirstName|LastName| *.xml` and the result is here:

```
<Title>ABC System</Title>
<Amount>50000</Amount>
<AwardID>1000</AwardID>
<FirstName>Name</FirstName>
<LastName>Thanks</LastName>
```

and now, I tried to use `sed` to replace strings and get things done. But it does not get things done.

What options should I use to get it.

```
sed -i "" 's/Title//g'
```

Results as a txt file:

```
ABC System, 50000, 100, Name, Thanks
```

#### Update

I can do it separately.

```
$ grep -E 'AwardID|AwardAmount|FirstName|LastName' 1433501.xml > test
$ sed -E '/AwardID|AwardAmount|FirstName|LastName/s/.*>([^<]+)<.*/\1/' test
```

43856
1433501
Faisal
Hossain

```
$ sed -E '/AwardID|AwardAmount|FirstName|LastName/s/.*>([^<]+)<.*/\1/' test | paste -sd',' -
```

43856,1433501,Faisal,Hossain

but when I put xxx.xml -> *.xml, I need to put new line. What should I put?

#### Update

AwardTable

```
xml sel -t -v //AwardID -o , -v //AwardAmount -nl *.xml > AwardTable.csv
```

InvestigatorTable

```
xml sel -t     -v //AwardID  -m '//Investigator[RoleCode = "Principal Investigator"]' -o , -v FirstName -o , -v LastName  -b -o [PI]    -m '//Investigator[RoleCode = "Co-Principal Investigator"]' -o , -v FirstName -o , -v LastName  -b  -o [CoPI]   -nl *.xml
```

How should I get data for InvestigatorTable? How can I have following formats?

```
ID, Firstname, Lastname, Role
12345, FirstName, LastName, PI
12345, FirstName, LastName, Co-PI
12345, FirstName, LastName, Former-PI


xml sel -t     -v //AwardID -o , -v //AwardAmount     -m '//Investigator[RoleCode = "Principal Investigator"]' -o , -v FirstName -o , -v LastName -o [PI] -b     -m '//Investigator[RoleCode = "Former Principal Investigator"]' -o , -v FirstName -o , -v  LastName -o [FoPI]  -b     -m '//Investigator[RoleCode = "Co-Principal Investigator"]' -o , -v FirstName -o , -v LastName -o [CoPI] -b     -nl *.xml
```

I can get like this

```
1417948,93147,M. Lee,Allison[PI],Jennifer,Arrigo[CoPI],Cynthia,Chandler[CoPI],Kerstin,Lehnert[CoPI]
1417966,574209,Robb,Lindgren[PI]
1418062,253000,Julia,Coonrod[PI],Gary,Harrison[FoPI]
```

I can do it manually now but please help it for me.

#### Update

Please help me to get the results with structures

```
AwardID, FirstName, LastName, Role
```

Comment: @jaypal thank you so much. I tried it many times. But still I have a problem. Do you mind if you see a real data here. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2fmkldddh1ct18s/VB7quD4Nw9

Comment: My OS X has shown bunch of what I don't want to see, that's why I tried to use grep. I have tons of xml files.

Comment: @Whymarrh Thanks. I was not familiar with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk would do it:

```
awk -v ORS=", " -F '[<>]' '
    /Title|Amount|AwardID|FirstName|LastName/ {print $3} 
    END {printf "\b\b \n"}
' << EOF
<Title>ABC System</Title>
<Amount>50000</Amount>
<AwardID>1000</AwardID>
<FirstName>Name</FirstName>
<LastName>Thanks</LastName>
EOF
```

```
ABC System, 50000, 1000, Name, Thanks
```

With multiple files, I assume you want a newline for each file. GNU awk v4 has an extension: ENDFILE

```
gawk -v ORS=", " -F '[<>]' '
    /Title|Amount|AwardID|FirstName|LastName/ {print $3} 
    ENDFILE {printf "\b\b \n"}
' *.xml
```

otherwise it's a bit more work:

```
awk -v ORS=", " -F '[<>]' '
    /Title|Amount|AwardID|FirstName|LastName/ {print $3} 
    FNR == 1 && FILENAME != ARGV[1] {printf "\b\b \n"}
    END {printf "\b\b \n"}
' *.xml
```

For robustness, you should be using an XML parser or XSLT transformation.

---

Given your sample xml files, here's a solution using [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), an xml processing tool I like:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v //AwardTitle -o , -v //AwardAmount -o , -v //AwardID -m //Investigator -o , -v FirstName -o , -v LastName -b -nl 1419538.xml 1424234.xml
```

```
IBDR: Workshop on Successful Approaches for Development and Dissemination of Instrumentation for Biological Research - May 1-2, 2014; Rosslyn, VA,49990,1419538,Sameer,Sonkusale,Valencia,Koomson,Eduardo,Rosa-Molinar
RAPID: Role of Physical, Chemical and Diffusion Properties of 4-Methyl-cyclohexane methanol in Remediating Contaminated Water and Water Pipes,49999,1424234,Daniel,Gallagher,Andrea,Dietrich,Paolo,Scardina
```

If you want to use another XSLT tool, here's the generated stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="exslt">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
      <xsl:with-param name="select" select="//AwardTitle"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
      <xsl:with-param name="select" select="//AwardAmount"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
      <xsl:with-param name="select" select="//AwardID"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:for-each select="//Investigator">
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="FirstName"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="LastName"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="value-of-template">
    <xsl:param name="select"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$select"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($select)[position()&gt;1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

The schema is not great. Specifically, it's not flexible: what if there are more than 5 investigators? You need something like this:

Perhaps more simple:

> Award table: id, title, amount
>   AwardInvestigators table: award_id, firstname, lastname, role

---

BTW, I read the question more carefully. I've amended by xmlstarlet command a bit to ensure the Principal Investigator's name is first:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t \
    -v //AwardID -o , -v //AwardAmount \
    -m '//Investigator[RoleCode = "Principal Investigator"]' -o , -v FirstName -o , -v LastName  -b \
    -m '//Investigator[RoleCode = "Co-Principal Investigator"]' -o , -v FirstName -o , -v LastName  -b \
    -nl \
*.xml
```

Comment: wow it works very well. then how can I put EOF file as many of files? I means results of grep

Comment: Thank you so much! @glenn jackman "newline" is really needed for me. It gives an almost perfect results. I would like to ask one more. Some XMLs have several "firstname", "lastname".

Comment: it has several <Investigator elements> of PI and Co-PI. Problem is here. I though first elements of Investigator is PI and following is CoPI. But it's not. some has it randomly. Could you see the file I put . Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, and ...? What output do you wish to see? Please update your question.

Comment: Final purpose is to import these data into table on DB. Do you recommend to use XML. I was trying to use XML, and noticed the XML format is not good. That's why I want to use grep to just get what I want to have. I will try the tool.

Comment: http://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/download.jsp this is what I want to import into DB.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the XML format. What's your DB schema? What's the plan to import the data?

Comment: really? then it's my bad. I will put the schema (MySQL). Any comments are welcome for the schema.

Comment: They can only one PI and up-to four Co-PI. Thanks for the great and simple schema. However, it's more complicated to import data. You suggest that make two tables and import it separately. collect?

Comment: My last edit to my answer will extract the data in the format you need for the single table.

Comment: I learn many things from you including awk and xmlstrlet. Now I am available to get the format I need for the single table. Thank you so much! @glenn jackman :]

Comment: Now I am trying to get two formats for two tables you suggest. Appreciate your help again!

Comment: Due to using *.xml, I get "Argument list too long error". Any options can I use? @glenn jackman

Comment: yes: `find . -name '*.xml' -print | xargs awk 'awk program'` -- that will invoke awk several times, each time supplying several filenames.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do it:

```
sed -nE '/Title|Amount|AwardID|FirstName|LastName/s/.*>([^<]+)<.*/\1/p' *.xml | paste -sd',' -
```

With your sample data, it gave the following output:

```
$ sed -nE '/Title|Amount|AwardID|FirstName|LastName/s/.*>([^<]+)<.*/\1/p' xmlfile | paste -sd',' -
Collaborative Research: Using the Rurutu hotspot to evaluate mantle motion and absolute plate motion models,137715,1433097,Jasper,Konter
```

Comment: thank you so much. One thing I would like to ask is how to put 'newline' every next files?